# How to upgrade to StyleCop 4.4 and have it run with each build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010, I was using Style Cop 4.3. I added the following key to my app.config so that StyleCop would run with each build.

```
<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\Microsoft\StyleCop\v4.3\Microsoft.StyleCop.targets" />-
</Project>
```

When I upgraded to StyleCop 4.4, I tried to change it to:

```
   <Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft StyleCop 4.4.0.14\Microsoft.StyleCop.dll" /> 
</Project>
```

I also changed my project to use version 4 of the Client Framework.

But I get the error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft StyleCop 4.4.0.14\Microsoft.StyleCop.dll(1,1): The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

I tried referencing all of the DLLs in that folder, same result.

Comment: It looks like you didn't install the MSBuild Integration component during setup (you want a .targets file, not .dll). And you may want to try 4.7, it's out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed what you're importing -- from `Microsoft.Stylecop.targets` to `Microsoft.Stylecop.dll`. [Make sure you've got `MSBuild Integration` installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/source-analysis-msbuild-integration.aspx) and try again.